# Pause css sprite for a second after loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, sprite

Is there any way(with css) to pause the sprite after last step for a one or more seconds ? I have tried to add one more step or the same bg-position from 80% to 100% but it didnt work.

```css
.sprite {
  animation: anim 2000ms steps(16) infinite;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/9FprJ5C.png) left center no-repeat;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite"></div>
```

Comment: I think that it isn't the duplicate. As you can see the right answer there won't work here. Also this animation is with steps

Comment: I tried to find solution but upto that it is better animation than currently working. https://jsfiddle.net/aLnmh97e/4/

Comment: thank you ketan I knew about this but I need to add the pause after thats why I added the "disappearance" but still thank you.

Comment: I think the only way to get a pause is for you to add extra frames to your sprite, most ways I have seen say that you need to leave off the last percentage of the keyframes but this seems to cause the sprite to rewind.  If you add extra frames, it will seem like it is pausing:  https://jsfiddle.net/rstkqoLL/2/

Comment: Yes I think that is right Pete but I was hoping to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the animation reach the end by 50%? i.e. after 1 second so that from 50%-100% it pauses:

```
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
}
```

```css
.sprite {
  animation: anim 2000ms steps(16) infinite;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/9FprJ5C.png) left center no-repeat;
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1440px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite"></div>
```

Comment: yes basically its the same when i would pause it from 80% the fish will disappear for that 50% or 20%